# Different height for alternative cell in UITableView

Tags: iphone

How to make a alternate cell with a different height?

I need height for cell1 is 60 and cell2 is 30....

how can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set the height of cell from the delegate method of table view

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (indexPath.row==0)
     {
        return 60;
     }
     else if(indexPath.row==1)
     {
        return 20;
     }
}
```

and so on....

Happy coding....

Answer (score 2):

Use the modulus operator and you dont need an if case for every row index :)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
     {
        return 60;
     }
     else
     {
        return 30;
     }
}
```

Comment: indexPath.row % 2 == 0 may be replaced by !(indexPath.row & 1)

Comment: return 60 / (indexPath.row & 1 + 1); But remember, there is always someone reading your code later...