# different different height for each row in UITableView

Tags: iphone

how to make the first three row height should be 60 and remaining row height should be 25 in UITableView.

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this link you can get the idea how we have to do it

[different-height-for-alternative-cell-in-uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529246/different-height-for-alternative-cell-in-uitableview/3529295#3529295)

or you can use the below delegate function

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (indexPath.row < 3)
     {
        return 60;
     }
     else
     {
        return 25;
     }
}
```

HAppy Coding...