# increasing the height of custom cell

Tags: iphone

I am working on a custom tableviewcell and trying to increase its height. I dont want to do it from my viewcontroller. Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to do it in the view controller? The view controller is usually responsible for dealing with such things since most of the time it's the one acting as the delegate for your `UITableView`.

Comment: because i am designing the cell in a different class and wants to do all of designing work for the cell in that custom class. Is it possible?...

Comment: You can try my updated solution, but it may be a bit costly.

Comment: @jacob i dont feel it will give me any benefit, as it is still being done from viewconroller. so i am feeling i will have to manage with viewcontroller delegate method, as suggested by u earlier, in addition i am planning to save the height of row in a varible in app delegate. thanks for helping...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different height for alternative cell in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529246/different-height-for-alternative-cell-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually *need* to do it from your `UITableViewDelegate`.

What you *can do* though, is use `UITableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to get the actual cell and call `isKindOfClass:` on it, and if it matches the type of your custom cell, you're golden.

Implement the [`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) method and return the desired height for the specified row:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   if([cell isKindOfClass:[YourCustomCell class]]) return someHeight;
   return 44.0;
}
```

Comment: but i wanted to make a custom cell which can be used straightaway without making any changes in its design..... is it possible doing it without using delegate method of tableview?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you *have* to do it from your controller in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. There is no other way to do it. :(

Comment: Gah, going my memory here :) Now I'll have to actually check it. Thanks for the heads-up.