# Manage height of UITableView cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am very new to iPhone Development. I am fetching data from the table and putting it onto the UITableViewCell. But sometimes this data is very small and sometimes may be large. According to the data size I need to manage the height of cell and data is displayed properly in a cell with multiline if it doesn't fit to single line. Is there any other option for me instead of UITableView or I am in Right way. If yes then how should I proceed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different height for alternative cell in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3529246/)

Answer (score 3):

use this delegate it will increase the row size

-(CGFloat)tableView :(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

```
 {
    return 80;   //value can be changed depending, how much height you need.
 }
```

Comment: @Ravi if this answer is correct then can you pls click on the tick on left side. thank you

Answer (score 0):

A `UITableView` is ok for you. In your [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:), you can use

```
– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

to set the row height. Now, if your data is displayed correctly or not, it depends on the content you are managing in the table view cell. `UITextField` is intrinsically one-line; but you could try with `UITextView`.

Otherwise, if you are looking for more advanced possibilities, have a look at this tutorial about [customizing cell view content](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html).

Have a look at this S.O. topic[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728704/resizing-uitextview) for a snippet of code about calculating the size of string.

Comment: But how I know that how much data is coming from database field and if needed to show it in multiline?