# How to set a UITableView static cell to a custom height?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, row-height

I have a UITableView with static cells and I am trying to change the height of the cell when it meets a condition. The conditions are being met but the cell heights won't change.

The code I am using is

```
[self.tableView setRowHeight:10];
```

And

```
self.tableView rowHeight = 10;
```

Neither of these will change the row height of the cells
Is there another way to change them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different height for alternative cell in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529246/different-height-for-alternative-cell-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to implement the following delegate-method in your tableview's .m:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return customTableCellHeight;
}
```

And then change the value of customTableCellHeight:

```
if (condition) {
    customTableCellHeight = 80; // or whatever
}
```

When your table cell height needs to change (like when the condition changes, you need to call

```
 [self.tableView reloadData]; //This calls heightForRowAtIndexPath for all cells
```

Comment: It doesn't need the `reloadData` call.

Comment: You need to call reloadData not inside heightForRowAtIndexPath, but outside of it, when the *condition* changes. This will cause the recalculation of heights and will allow dynamic sizing of cells.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this for all row of tableview

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return 100
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can create the dynamic cell with Text height then you can set the static and dynamic cell both in on table view

Here is link to dynamic cell with text
[How to change cell height dynamically in UITableView static cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420980/how-to-change-cell-height-dynamically-in-uitableview-static-cell)