# How to change the height of a custom cell individually within a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to change the height of each cell individually based on how long my `UILabel` is, but it does not seem to change.

I have found the following question: [How to change cell height dynamically in UITableView static cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420980/how-to-change-cell-height-dynamically-in-uitableview-static-cell)

I tried the solution from that question:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //return 110;

    NewsFlashCustomCell *cell;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell.messageLabel.frame.origin.y + cell.messageLabel.frame.size.height;

}
```

However, that seems to do nothing.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I'd like the height of the cells containing "tidal wave" and "mashup" to be smaller than the last 2 cells since it has a longer message.

I cannot perform a `indexPath.row` check to change each cell individually because each message is pulled from a database, so the length of the message varies.

What can be done?

In case it helps, here's a screenshot of my constraints:

[image]

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I added the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/34959642/5085393

Comment: Try this https://mkswap.net/m/ios/2015/07/08/uitableviewcells-with-dynamic-height.html

Comment: using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` should work from iOS 8 & above, like @bhargavbajani 's link

Comment: adding `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` does not work :(

Comment: Have you set your UILabel number of lines to 0?

Comment: Yes, I set number of lines = 0

Answer (score 0):

Please write following line in `viewDidLoad`:

```
_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Please make sure of following points:

1. Dont create height constraint of label
2. Make width of that label equal to screen size or content view
3. Apply leading, trailing, top and bottom constraint
4. Dont write `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method

Please let me know the results

EDIT :

Write following line in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.contentView.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: please check description

Comment: Have you tried - lblgoal.numberOfLines = 0;
lblgoal.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; //NSLineBreakByWordWrapping for iOS 6

Comment: this does not work, all cells height remain the same

Answer (score 0):

If you can't set try with other method reduce the label font size depend upon the cell height .

```
label.numberOfLines=0;
 label.clipsToBounds=YES;
 label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
 label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate height for label from its length of text and do it like following way:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return [self calculateHeightForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

#pragma mark - cell height handling
-(CGFloat)calculateHeightForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexP{


    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width-22, defaultHeightOfYourLabel)];

    NSString *strLbl;
    strLbl = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexP.row];

    lbl.text = strLbl;

    if (IS_IPAD) {

        [lbl setFont:fontRegular15];

    }else{

        [lbl setFont:fontRegular12];

    }

    UIFontDescriptor * fontDLBLTime = [lbl.font.fontDescriptor
                                       fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];

    if (IS_IPAD) {

        [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDLBLTime size:15]];

    }else{

        [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDLBLTime size:12]];

    }

    [lbl setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];

    [lbl setNumberOfLines:0];

    int noOfLines = [GlobalFunction lineCountForLabel:lbl];

    CGFloat height = [GlobalFunction heightForWidth:lbl.frame.size.width usingFont:lbl.font forLabel:lbl];

    if (noOfLines>1) {

        return height + 33; //here 33 is sum of top and bottom space from view.

    }

    return 50; //default height of cell.

}
```

In your class implement following methods:

```
#define CGFLOAT_MAX_HEIGHT 2000.0

+ (int)lineCountForLabel:(UILabel *)label {

    return ceil([self heightForWidth:label.frame.size.width usingFont:label.font forLabel:label] / label.font.lineHeight);

}
+(CGFloat)heightForWidth:(CGFloat)width usingFont:(UIFont *)font forLabel:(UILabel *)lbl{
    NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    CGSize labelSize = (CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX_HEIGHT};
    CGRect r = [lbl.text boundingRectWithSize:labelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:context];
    return r.size.height;
}
```

You can customize `lbl` on basis of your font and label size.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have your label constrain the bounds of your cell, like your already doing. Be sure to include padding around it so it looks nicer.
2. In your `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` calculate the height required for your label (it is important you have your label correctly configured for multiline and/or word wrapping)

Calculate the required height of label

```
CGRect frame = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(cell.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil];
```

3. Return the calculated height plus padding

   frame.size.height + TopPadding + Bottom Padding

This is a general approach to have a dynamically sizing cell.

Note: Sometimes this is off by a few points so you may need to add up 5 extra points in the cell height to get all the text fitting in the label.

Comment: no change in height, I set lines=0 with Word Wrap and no changes with your code implemented in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`